# Do cpuidle governors and cpufreq governors work in mutual exclusion?

Tags: cpu-usage

My understanding is that when a CPU is in the [C0 state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Processor_states), the cpufreq governor decides what P-state the CPU should reside in. When a CPU goes idle, it falls from the C0 state to a deeper C-state. The cpuidle govenor, say menu, takes over in deciding which C-state the CPU should go to, once the CPU goes idle. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You have 7 questions and not single accept... maybe it's time to try accepting one?